# Delete SearchHits from SearchResponse Object Java [ElasticSearch]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am querying elastic from my java application, which is giving me a `SearchResponse` object. I want to do some processing of this data and delete some SearchHit from it.

```
SearchResponse response = getElasticSearchClient().search(searchQuery.getQuery(), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHit[] searchHit = response.getHits().getHits()
```

I want to delete some `SearchHit` from the above fetched list of `SearchHit`.

How can I do this ? Can I delete the SearchHit from this SearchResponse object or I need to create a new list of SearchHit Objects and create a new SearchResponse from it (and how to keep all the value fields from the original SearchResponse).